# How does bdist_wheel know my package is for py3 and not cp38?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I generate wheels by executing setuptools.setup():

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

When I look on the pypi page of [mpu](https://pypi.org/project/mpu/#files), I see:

[image]

When I look at the PyPI page of [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), I see:

[image]

How does setuptools / pypi know which Python version my package is for (py3 in the column "Python version" and in the file name) and how does it know that is for any platform (none)?

For numpy, it knows the operating system it was build for (macosx / manylinux1 / win32 for numpy) and the cpu architecture (is that the right name? I mean 10_6_intel, i686, x86_64).

Where does the difference come from? Is cp35 short for "cpython 3.5"? If so, why not only "py35"?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/the-challenges-in-designing-a-library-for-pep-425/

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#details